# Given a DAG, the length of the longest path and the node in which it ends, how do I retrace my steps so I can print each node of the longest path?

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-theory

I'm working on a problem of finding the most parallelepipeds that can be stored into each other given a list of parallelepipeds.

My approach was to represent the graph with an adjacency list, do a topological sort and then for each node in the topological array "unrelax" the edges, giving me the longest path.

Below is the code but I don't think it matters for the question.

```
typedef struct Edge {
int src;            /* source node  */
int dst;            /* destination node  */
struct Edge *next;
} Edge;


int maxend;  //node in which the longest path ends
int mp; // longest path

for (int i = 0; i < G.n; i++)
{   
    int j = TA[i];             //TA is the topological sorted array
    if (g->edges[j] != NULL) 
    {                           
        if(DTA[j] == -1) DTA[j] = 0; 
        
        Edge* tmp = G.edges[j];
    
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {   
            if(DTA[tmp->src] >= DTA[tmp->dst]){     //DTA is the array that keeps track of the maximum distance of each node in TA
                DTA[tmp->dst] = DTA[tmp->src]+1;   
                if (DTA[tmp->dst] > mp) {
                    mp = DTA[tmp->dst];
                    maxend = tmp->dst;
                }
            }    
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

In the end I have the lenght of the longest path and the node in which said path ends, but how do I efficiently recreate the path?

If parallelepiped A contains parallelepiped B and parallelepiped B contains parallelepiped C that means that parallelepiped A parallelepiped box C aswell, which means that each edge has a weight of 1 and Vertex where the longest path starts has the furthest node of the path in his adjaceny list.

I've thought of 3 solutions but none of them look great.

1. Iterate the edges of each vertex that has weight 0 (so no predecessors) and if there is a choice avoid choosing the edge that connects it with the furthest node (As said before, the shortest path between the starting node and the ending node will be 1)
2. In the the array that tracks the maximum distance of each node in the topologically sorted array: start from the index representing the furthest node we found, see if the previous node has a compatible distance (as in, the previous node has 1 less distance than the furthest node). If it does, check it's adjaceny list to see if the furthest node is in it (because if the furthest node has a distance of 10 there could be several nodes that have a distance of 9 but are unconnected to it). Repeat until we reach the root of the path.
3. Most probable candidate so far, create an array of pointers that keeps track of the "maximum" parent of each node. In the code above everytime a node has it's maximum distance changed it means that it's parent node, if it had any, had a longer distance than the previous parent, which means we can change the maximum parent associated with the current node.

Edit: I ended up just allocating a new array and everytime I updated the weight of a node ( DTA[tmp->src] >= DTA[tmp->dst] )  I also stored the number of the source edge in the cell of the destination edge.

Comment: Can't you just start with the biggest box, then the 2nd biggest, then the 3rd biggest...?

Comment: @NealBurns  Yes.  That would be a sensible first attack on the problem.   KISS is always good.

Comment: @NealBurns  I believe your simple approach will give the optimal answer if the boxes are all cubes.  Otherwise, it may miss the optimum arrangement for irregular hexahedrons ( which I assume the OP is considering - he doesn't say )

Comment: Yeah, I updated the post. Boxes are parallelepipeds that can't be rotated

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get what you mean by _'Given a DAG, **the longest path** and the node in which it ends (...)'_.  
If you are _given_ the longest path, what is the problem with printing nodes on that path??

Comment: @CiaPan poor choice of words on my part, it should be given *the lenght* of the longest path

Comment: Dear @JustJohn , u may [edit] it to improve the question clarity.. ( :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the graph edge u <- v indicates that box u is big enough to contain v.

I suggest you dump the topological sort.  Instead:

```
SET weight of every edge to -1
LOOP
   LOOP over leaf nodes ( out degree zero, box too small to contain others )
       Run Dijkstra algorithm ( gives longest path, with predecessors )
       Save length of longest path, and path itself
   SAVE longest path
   REMOVE nodes on longest path from graph
   IF all nodes gone from graph
        OUTPUT saved longest paths ( lists of nested boxes )
        STOP
```

This is called a "greedy" algorithm.  It is not guaranteed to give the optimal result.  But it is fast and simple, always gives a reasonable result and often does give the optimal.

Comment: I was under the impression that Dijkstra would not work for negative edges, is this a special case since weight 1 basically means unweighted?

Comment: The standard method for finding longest paths is to run Dijkstra with negative weights.  What is cannot handle is some -ve and some +ve  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Answer (score 0):

[I think this solves it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs), unless there's something I don't understand.

The highest-weighted path in a DAG is equivalent to the lowest-weighted path if you make the edge weights negative. Then you can apply Dijkstra's algorithm directly.

> A longest path between two given vertices s and t in a weighted graph
> G is the same thing as a shortest path in a graph −G derived from G by
> changing every weight to its negation.

This might even be a special case of Dijkstra that is simpler... not sure.

To retrieve the longest path, you start at the end and go backwards:

1. Start at the vertex with the greatest DTA `V_max`
2. Find the edges that end at `V_max` (`edge->dest = V_max`)
3. Find an edge `Src_max` where the DTA value is 1 less than the max (`DTA[Src_max] == DTA[V_max] - 1`)
4. Repeat this recursively until there are no more source vertices

To make that a little more efficient, you can reverse the endpoints of the edges on the way down and then follow the path back to the start. That way each reverse step is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

I think the option 3 is most promising. You can search for the longest path with DSF starting from all the root vertices (those without incoming edges) and increasing the 'max distance' for each vertex encountered.

This is quite a simple solution, but it may traverse some paths more than once. For example, for edges (a,f), (b,c), (c,f), (d,e), (e,c)

```txt
a------------f
            /
   b----c--/
       /
d--e--/
```

(all directed rightwards)
the starting vertices are a, b, and d, the edge (c,f) will be traversed twice and the vertex f distance will be updated three times. If we append the rest of alphabet to f in a simple chain,

```txt
a------------f-----g--  -  -  ---y---z 
            /
   b----c--/
       /
d--e--/
```

the whole chain from f to z will be probably traversed three times, too.

You can avoid this by separating the phases and modifying the graph between them: after finding all the starting vertices (a, b, d) increment the distance of each vertex available from those (f, c, e), then remove starting vertices and their edges from the graph - and re-iterate as long as some edges remain.
This will transform the example graph after the first step like this:

```txt
             f-----g--  -  -  ---y---z 
            /
        c--/
       /
   e--/
```

and we can see all the junction vertices (c and f) will wait until the longest path *to them* is found before letting the analysis go further past them.

That needs iterative seeking for starting vertices, which may be time consuming unless you do some preprocessing (for example, counting all incoming edges for each vertex and storing vertices in some sorting data structure, like an integer-indexed multimap or a simple min-heap.)

The question remains open, whether the whole overhead of truncating a graph and rescaning it for new root vertices makes a net gain compared with multiple traversing some final parts of common paths in your particular graph...